# How to conditionally load JavaScript with template.php

Tags: theming

I have a content type that has involves some js magic for every node. How can I code it into template.php so that it is loaded only on display of the content type? I don't want the js to load uselessly on every page. My php skills are pretty shallow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[js_injector](http://drupal.org/project/js_injector) module lets you control which pages you want to include your code.

[CSS_injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector) does the same for css.